# Is there any way to find out encoding of data existing in MySql

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, database-migration, iso-8859-1

I have to convert character set of my MySql DB from Latin1 to UTF-8. I have gone through a lot of articles for this purpose.

A lot of articles suggested to use `mysqldump`, that is dumping MySql DB in latin1 encoding, replace character set from latin1 to UTF-8 and load it through `mysql` with character set UTF-8.

Another suggestion is to convert each character/text related column to binary format first then convert it to correct character/text type alone with setting the character set to UTF-8.

But I wonder how to test DB after migration? Is there any way to find of encoding of original data stored in the column as I read there might be a chance to see data with different encoding other than column's default ending?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues) explains how to do `SELECT HEX(col)...` to see what is really in the table.  Then it enumerates what you it represents if it is UTF-8:  Hex `C3yy` for Western Europe; `Dxyy` for Eastern Europe and the Middle East; etc.

If you have some 8-bit encoding that does not follow that patter, let's see the hex, plus what it should show as; it should be possible to deduce the encoding (latin1, cp1251, etc).